# Is Android OS only used for ARM CPUs?

Tags: android, arm, smartphone

If not, can APK files for Android run on either ARM CPUs or non-ARM CPUs?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: http://www.android-x86.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android runs on other CPU's as well. Such as [Intel Atom](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android).

If your app uses only Java then it doesn't matter. It can run on any CPU and you won't care. You don't have to program specifically per CPU when working with Java.

If your app uses native code ([NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)), then you'll have to prepare your APK to run on all CPU's you want to support. Instructions such as [these](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/creating-and-porting-ndk-based-android-apps-for-ia/) explain how to do so.

If you're not sure if you need NDK or not, then you probably don't. NDK is needed in very specific cases such as high performance games. If you're just making a regular app, you will probably use Java only.

Regarding the APK issue - if you need to support multiple architectures you can do this using both a single APK or multiple APK's. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CpuArchOptions) for more info.

Comment: Please note that Java isn't used on Android. Android apps can be compiled from various languages.

Comment: You are incorrect sir. Android relies heavily on the Dalvik JVM. Dalvik is primarily designed around Java although other languages can be used as well. It is true that Dalvik isn't a traditional JVM and uses DEX files instead of JAR files, but it's still bytecode with JIT compilation.

Comment: It is bytecode with JIT - but it is not JVM. It is not Java. It is completely different in architecture (stack vs. registers) - please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Comment: At this point it's just nitpicking, but the entire Android SDK is built around Java API (http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). Also, all the core non-native Android code is implemented in Java (http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/)

Comment: You are right and I initially gave a + ;-) I simply commented to note that Android and Dalvik is not Java/JVM. After spending time with byte code for each platform the differences are very clear. Android is built around compatibility _form_ Java/JVM not _to_ it. It is a VERY small detail indeed - but worth noticing.

Comment: Is there any website that shows how popular each CPU architecture is for Android? All I've found is the one of Unity, but it shows it for GPU : http://stats.unity3d.com/mobile/index-android.html

Comment: In one of case, I'm using some 3rd party library, and found that all lib not build for all available architecture. And that causes of exception **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader** runtime. Since runtime system goes for more appropriate search available there. 

Any suggestion what can be done in this case??

Answer (score 1):

Android supports, ARM, MIPS, Power Architecture, x86 prosessors..X86 cpu's are like Intel Atom and other cpu's that are single core like the Pentium M. Android needs atleast a 480MHZ Cpu to run smooth anything below will be slow. 
and as talkol mentioned if you're programming in java (most likely) the architecture doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, for APK's to run, they will need to be installed on the Android OS. And the Android OS should support the architecture concerned.

Now, I am not sure if this is an exception, nor do I know if the software employs some *trickry to function like an Android emulator*. But [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) allows Android apps to install and run on the Windows, Mac and Chrome OS platforms(**ARM and x86 only**). Or it could merely be the fact that the Android OS now works / is supported by 3 other platform besides the ARM platform. Namely:

1. [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture)
2. [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android-x86): *Unsure if this is a relevant link*
3. [i.MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I.MX)

Besides, in the AVD, you will see that you have the option of choosing between ARM, Intel x86 and MIPS architecture when creating a new / or editing an existing Virtual Device (*provided you have installed them from the SDK Manager)*.

So, bottom line: If the Architecture is capable of running the Android OS, your app is capable of running on it too.

Comment: i.MX is an ARM SoC family in much the same way as TI OMAP, nVidia Tegra, and Qualcomm Snapdragon are.

Answer (score 0):

Android - the open source project - is used on almost any CPU out in the wild.

APK files can contain a wide array of types. Most of these will allow the APK to run on any CPU - but certain types as shared libraries etc. may be included and may brake cross platform compatibility.

Please refer to [the article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) for an overview on the APK file contents.